# Inter- or extrapolate from a cubic spline cox-proportional hazard model using RMS package

Tags: r, prediction, predict, rms

I am using the `cph` function in the RMS package to assess the association of WEIGHT with an EVENT outcome. I am using cubic spline with 3 knots.

How can I use the model to predict the hazard ratio for weights that were not included in the original data? i.e. How can I use the model to inter- or extrapolate?

Here is an example:

```
set.seed(123)
library(rms)
WT <- rnorm(10, 30, 10)
EVENT <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10)
TIME <- c(seq(1,10,1))

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(TIME,EVENT,WT))
fit <- cph(Surv(TIME, EVENT==1) ~ rcs(WT, 3), data = df)
fit

d = datadist(df)
options(datadist = 'd')

Predict(fit, WT) # this predicts hazard for WT included in the data
```

How can I use the model `fit` to predict hazrad at `WT==70` for example?

I am using R studio.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but how about `Predict(fit, WT=70)`

Comment: @Edward Nope. I tried :- )

Comment: Works for me. I get: `yhat = -1.234295`. What did you get?

Comment: Ooops! Yes, it does. I added `==` instead of `=`.